# Setting values of variables with an array/loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, variables, loops

How can I set the values of variables with a loop?
For example:

```
String cur[]= {"A","B"};
String strA,strB;
for(int i =0;i < cur.length;i++) {
  str+i = "Blah";
}
```

what should go in the "str+i" part so it sets strA and strB to "Blah"?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't do that. Instead, you create a collection of some type. For example, you might use a map:

```
String[] cur = { "A", "B" };
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>;
for (String name : cur)
    map.put(name, "Blah");
}
```

Unless you use reflection (which won't help for local variables), you can't "compute" the variable name to use... and you *shouldn't* be using reflection for something like this.

That's assuming you want to access values by a string name. If you can use a contiguous range of integers (starting from 0), then an array or a `List<T>` might be more appropriate. It depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

There is no simple way of doing exactly what you want.  However, there is a simple alternative: instead of individually naming your Strings, just use a single array.

```
String[] cur = new String[2];
for (int i = 0; i < cur.length; ++i) {
    cur[i] = "Blah";
}
```

If you must access these Strings by name rather than index, look into creating a [`Map<String, String>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: I should have been more specific. I want to set the text of JLabels and JTextFields with the loop. Each label is named like lblA, lblB, txtA,etc. So if(x = i){ lbl+i.setText("something");} Right now I had to copy and paste a bunch of if statements, and replace the "A" part manually.

Comment: Is there a good reason that the labels need to be named lblA, lblB, etc.?  Think about whether the names are necessary, or if you can instead use an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You probably shouldn't.

To strictly what you want you should use probably the java.lang.reflect classes. It allows you do some sort of dynamic member access you see possible in languages such us javascript and/or ruby. But it seems overkill in this case.

Another other more useful solution is what mr. Jon Skeet proposed. Depending on your actual needs it might just work.

Comment: @dave that's true :). I added some clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something kind of like that although I'm not sure why you'd want to:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field; 

public class Test { 
    static public String strA, strB; 

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception { 
        String cur[]= {"A","B"}; 

        for(int i =0;i < cur.length;i++) { 
            Field field = Test.class.getField("str" + cur[i]); 
            field.set(null, "Blah"); 
        } 
        System.out.println(strA); 
        System.out.println(strB); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can do this ... but you shouldn't.  This kind of thing is orders of magnitude slower than non-reflective code, and also more complicated and more fragile,

Comment: That would depend on purpose of the question.  There are plenty of valid reasons to assign a dynamic list of properties such as configuring a plugin style class from a configuration file where the framework doesn't know the sub-type.